# Getting PID of sshd

Tags: bash, shell

I am executing sshd in a bash script using

```
$ /usr/sbin/sshd
```

How do I get the process ID of this sshd that I executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sshd` will typically write a PID file; by default this is at `/var/run/sshd.pid`. You can use this to find the process ID of the listening `sshd` process. You should be aware that `sshd` may fork several subprocesses as it works, so what you want really depends on what you intend to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this command:

```
ps aux | grep -e /usr/sbin/sshd | grep -v grep | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f2
```

or

```
cat /var/run/sshd.pid
```

Comment: There might be multiple sshd processes running. Moreover, I want to know the PID of the last executed process and I want to do this from inside a script. Its not a background process, so I can't simply use $!